# Term for alluding to options that don't exist

Tags: fallacies

Is there a term for alluding to options that don't really exist or are extremly suboptimal? Something along the lines of "Well, if they don't like it they can always do something else." but when pressed, every other option of "something else" would end up killing the person. All my google searching pointed to False Dilemma, but that seems backwards as False Delemma is improperly restricting/ignoreing valid answers, while this question is more about pretending there are other unstated but valid answers when there arn't any.

Comment: The term "false choice" can be used either to refer to a false dichotomy, or to what you're referring to:  a choice that "isn't a choice at all."

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could find is Hobson's Choice, but it is not a perfect fit. The expression comes from the 17th century where a horse renter would tell his costumers 'You can pick any horse that is available; only horse closest to the door is available'. [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hobson%27s_choice) considers these take-it-or-leave-it situates Hobson's Choices. The definition given by the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hobson-s-choice) is closer to what you describe:

> a situation in which it seems that you can choose between different
> things or actions, but there is really only one thing that you can
> take or do:

Although a few articles on Google Scholar use the phrase, none of them actually analyze what a Hobson's Choice implies philosophically. If I were tasked with writing a philosophical paper about Hobson's Choices, I would look at the original case in terms of [negative and positive liberty](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liberty-positive-negative/), which are 2 different schools of thought on what it means to be free. Someone from the negative liberty school could claim that Hobson was limiting his customer's liberty by creating rules that limited their possible actions. Someone from the positive liberty school would focus on the motives of the customers and the context that requires them to rent horses rather than they horse-renting system itself.

Comment: "Positive liberty" and "negative liberty" as described by Isaiah Berlin aren't what you think. In particular, Berlin wouldn't apply either label to specific individual liberties. Berlin describes positive and negative *conceptions* of liberty, each conception purporting to encompass all of liberty. Each conception of liberty motivates political systems based on that conception. There is a great deal of overlap in the specific liberties entailed by the positive and negative conceptions of liberty.

Comment: Specifically, "negative liberty" is the conception of liberty that says you are not free only if someone else is preventing you from doing something. "Positive liberty" is the conception of liberty that says you are not free if someone else is preventing you from doing the right thing, *or* if you are prevented from doing the right thing because of factors internal to your mind, such as addiction, impulsivity, or lack of wisdom.

Comment: The idea that a "negative liberty" is a right not to be stopped from doing something, whereas a "positive liberty" is a right to do something, is completely wrong. It doesn't even make sense; the right to do something *is the same as* the right not to be stopped from doing it. Actually, both the positive and negative concept of liberty are about not being stopped from doing things. The positive concept of liberty just includes the idea of not being stopped by your own lack of self-control or virtue. https://cactus.dixie.edu/green/B_Readings/I_Berlin%20Two%20Concpets%20of%20Liberty.pdf

Comment: You are correct, so I edited my post to be less wrong. My description of Berlin's liberties is still simplistic, but my intention was more to provide the OP a place to continue researching the relevant issues, than to form a rigorous and complete analysis.